# Flutter: how can i get device_id and device_token in flutter 2.5.3?

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0

I want to get device information such as device_id and device_token for google and facebook sign-in, so that i can get data for the next dashboard-page as in following code

```
Body:{
  "token": "string",
  "device_info": {
    "device_token": "lfkjklfl", <---- //this field i need 
    "device_id": "jgkfjdgkfjdlgfd"
  }
}
```

i have used this [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) package for getting token, but their is no token type in this package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device_token` only you can get via `firebase messaging`.

Comment: or atleast how can i get android_id ?

Comment: device_id is that android_id

Comment: Device ID where is it? is it in device_info package ?

Comment: For that you can use this package :  https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus